# MapReduce on AWS

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce

Anybody played around with MapReduce on AWS yet? Any thoughts? How's the implementation?

Comment: How come when I asked questions like this they die in 4 secs with `not a real question` buls**it

Answer (score 15):

It's easy to get started.

Here's a FAQ: http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/faqs/

And here's the Getting Started Guide: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/GettingStartedGuide/

If you have an EC2 account already, you can enable MapReduce and have a sample application up and running in less than 10 minutes using the AWS Management Console.

I did the pre-packaged Word Count sample application, which returns a count of each word contained in about 20 MB of text.  You can provision up to 20 instances to run concurrently, though I just used 2 instances and the job completed in about 3 minutes.

The job returns a 300 KB alphabetized list of words and how often each word appears in the sample corpus.

I really like that MapReduce jobs can be written in my choice of Perl, Python, Ruby, PHP, C++, R, or Java.  The process was painless and straightforward, and the interface gives good feedback on the status of your instances and the job flow.

Be aware that, since AWS charges for a full hour when an instance is created, and since the MapReduce instances are automatically terminated at the end of the job flow, the cost of multiple fast-running job flows can add up quickly.

For example, if I create a job flow that uses 20 instances and returns results in 15 minutes, and then re-run the job flow 3 more times, I'll be charged for 80 hours of machine time even though I only had 20 instances running for 1 hour.

Comment: Our experiences as well, plus the slow start up time. It's only worth it if you have jobs that are likely to run for several hours.

Comment: The cluster is not necessarily automatically terminated, you can leave it running.

Answer (score 4):

You also have the possibility to run MapReduce (Hadoop) on AWS with [StarCluster](http://web.mit.edu/star/cluster/). This tool configures the cluster for you and has the advantage that you don´t have to pay the extra Amazon Elastic MapReduce Price (if you want to reduce your costs) and you could create your own Image (AMI) with your tools (this could be good if the installation of the tools can´t be done by a bootstrap script).

Answer (score 2):

It is very convenient because you don't have to administer your own cluster. You just pay per use so I think it is a good idea if you have a job that needs to run once in a while. We are running Amazon MapReduce just once a month so, for our usage, it is worth it.

However, as far as I can tell, a drawback of Amazon Map Reduce is that you can't tell which Operating System is running, or even its version. This caused me problems running c++ code that compiled with g++ 4.44, some of the OS images does not support cUrl library, etc.

If you don't need any special libraries for your use case, I would say go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Good answer by MB.

To be clear: you can run Hadoop clusters in two ways:
1) Run it on Amazon EC2 instances. This means that you have to install it, configure it, terminate it, etc.
2) Run it using Elastic MapReduce, or EMR: this is an automated way to run an Hadoop cluster on Amazon Web Services. You pay a little extra on top of the basic cost for EC2, but you don't need to manage anything: just upload your data, then your algorithm, then crunch. EMR will shut down the instances automatically once your jobs are finished.

Best,

Simone

Answer (score 1):

EMR is the best way to use available resources with a very little added cost over EC2 however you will how time saving and easy it is. Most of the MR implementation on Cloud are using this model i.e. Apache Hadoop on Windows Azure, Mortar Data etc.. I have worked on both Amazon EMR and Apache Hadoop on Windows Azure and found incredible to use.

Answer (score 1):

Also, depending on the type / duration of jobs you plan to run, you can use [AWS spot instances with EMR to get better pricing.](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/08/run-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-on-ec2-spot-instances.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am working with AWS EMR. It is pretty neat. I mean once you start up their cluster and login into their Master node. You can play around with the hadoop directory structure. And do pretty cool things.. If you have a edu account don;t forget to apply for a research grant. They give unto 100$ free credits to use their AWS.

Answer (score 0):

AWS EMR is a good choice when you use S3 storage for your data.
It provides out of the box integration with S3 for loading files and posting processed files.
In use cases where you need to run the job on demand, you are saved from the cost of running the whole cluster all the time, this really helps you save on instance hours.
Leveraging the above advantage, one can use AWS lambda to spawn event driven clusters.